# Solr - How to get a document that has the minimum price

Tags: solr, max, minimum

I have a Solr instance which contains documents that represent products. Each document has a `UnitPrice` attribute associated with it, which is of type `float`, in the `schema.xml`.

Is it possible to perform a query the would return me a document that has the minimum price? I would also like to find the document that has the maximum price.  Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`q={!lucene}*:*&sort=UnitPrice+asc&rows=1`

This will return the first result of a [MatchAllDocsQuery](https://builds.apache.org/job/Lucene-trunk/javadoc/core/org/apache/lucene/search/MatchAllDocsQuery.html) sorted by price.

Comment: Thanks for this. This will do nicely.  But I also found another way to do it. You can use the stats component which can be called as such. [http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=*:*&stats=true&stats.field=unitprice&rows=0&indent=true](http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=*:*&stats=true&stats.field=unitprice&rows=0&indent=true) This will give min and max values in one query as well as other useful information.

Comment: Is there any way to also get documents along with stats? Thank you.